# If a user had access to the terminal in a docker container can they do anything to destroy the hard drive its on?

Tags: docker, security, exploit

If a user had access to a root Ubuntu terminal in a docker container, can they do anything to destroy the hard drive or SSD it is on?

Link: gitlab.com/pwnsquad/term

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152978/is-it-possible-to-escalate-privileges-and-escaping-from-a-docker-container

Comment: @Z3R0DAY You can [edit] your question and include that link instead of posting it as comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker by default gives root access to containers.

Container can damage your **host** system only if you bypassed the container isolation mechanisms of Docker, otherwise the only damage can be done to the container itself, not host.

The simplest ways to break the isolation mechanisms are following:

- using Dockers' bind mounts, when you map host's path into container' path. In this case this path may be completely cleaned from inside container. Avoid bind mounts (use volumes) or mount in `ro` mode to avoid that
- using networking, specially `network=host` guarantees container access to all host's active network services and thus probably making host vulnerable to attacks on them. In this case you can connect to services, which are bound **locally** (to `127.0.0.1/localhost`) thus not expecting remote connections and as a result could be less protected.